# Token authentication for an ASP.NET Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I developed an ASP.Net website with cookie authentication.

After reading about CSRF attacks I decided to change my website to work with token authentication which will be saved in the client side.

So what I have done is:

1. used logins
2. user receives a token and saves it in the `sessionStorage`
3. user sends the token in the header of each `API` requests.

This works great.

Now the one thing that is missing for me is the page loads, meaning if a user tries to access a page before he is logged-in it should redirect him to the login page. This is something I want to do obviously before the page is loaded, for example before i had this code in the `Site.Master`:

```
if (!AuthCookieValidator.IsValid(HttpContext.Current))
{
    s_Logger.Info("the user is not authenticated, logging out!");
    Response.Redirect("/Login");
}
```

But now I can't implement this logic unless i keep both session based token + client side token.

What's the solution here?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having with the code you've posted?

Comment: That if the user tries to access a certain page, I want him to be redirected to the login page before the page loads, The code I added is for session based authentication(which is passed in every request). As for the token authentication where the client adds the token only to API requests

Comment: Are you using web forms - why can;t you just put the code you've posted in the page load event of the master page or any pages you want the user to be logged in to access.

Comment: don't reinvent the wheel. use @Html.AntiForgeryToken() + [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] + [Authorized]

Comment: Its not a webforms application, its actually a react + mvc (where the mvc acts as an API)

Comment: if it is a react app, then you wouldn't redirect from the API. The API would only return 401 if unauthenticated or 403 if unauthorized. The react app would need to do the redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my solution is like so:

1. User logins
2. User receives a token and saves it in the sessionStorage
3. User sends the token in the header of each API requests.
4. If the user tries to reach a url directly, before the react code starts to render the page it will send an authentication check request with the token and render accordingly.

Any comments are appreciated about my approach